# REDCap - reporting data back to user

Tags: data-transfer, redcap

I'm looking for a simple solution for a cooperative project where specimens will be mailed to me, and I would report several measurements back to the sender.

I need the originating site to fill out a form with some basic information (specimen ID, collection dates, shipment tracking #, etc). Then I need to let the site know I received the shipment - via the same form. Then, after some analytics, I need to report 3 numerical values (biomarker levels) back to the site.

Someone recommended REDCap for this project. I know I can do data collection with REDCap (the initial requisition form), but can I also report the values back with REDCap?

Comment: It sounds like there are a lot of moving pieces, so a simple solution may not be possible with any software.  REDCap has [an API and client-side packages in several languages](http://redcap-tools.github.io/projects/), which will allow you to connect it to other systems.  From the description above, the authentication aspect may be tricky to ensure that the PHI secure when communicating with outsiders.  Consider having your REDCap admin post your scenario to the [REDCap forums](https://community.projectredcap.org) (an account is required).  Provide more details about these outside parties.

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted. It's a pretty reasonable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears I found the solution, by talking to a REDCap expert. In case someone is interested, here's basic outline:

1. Create two forms: one for requisiton, another one for reporting data back to user.
2. Invite REDCap users to my project and give them read-only rights to the second form.
3. Put other users in Data Access Groups, so they only can see the requisitions (and results) from their own group.

This might work, but I decided to not go this way. In REDCap, an user has all rights by default, and I would have to limit them. In my application there is too much potential for data breach due to mistake in assigning rights and DAGs.

Comment: This solution is what I'd have suggested. It's neat, secure, and does what you need. You could even configure their user account to be able to view reports that you customise with aggregate information, if that is of benefit.

I wouldn't shy away from REDCap from fear of not using the user account roles and DAGs. Just test *thoroughly* prior to going live (giving the account details out).  With a combination of DAG (so that the user can only access records in the group - that they themselves created) and read-only access to the second form, you will absolutely get what you need.

Comment: You as an admin on the project have full rights, true, but when you add a user role, you would limit the rights for users in that role. Add yourself with a test account and test. Make sure you can see or modify anything you're not supposed to. Then add a DAG or two, add records to them and make sure you can only see those in your DAG. WARNING: if a user is not in a DAG then they will see all records. DAGs are limiting, not enabling. Only admins should not be in a DAG.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use REDCap with an email alert module enabled.

Configure a project with two forms:

One for the client to enter the information you need from them, and make that form anonymous - no user account needed, and collect an email address from them (to return results). For the example below let's call this form `[request]`.

The second form will be for you to enter the biomarker levels and whatever else you need to. This form only needs to be viewable and editable by you. Let's call this `[results]`.

Then, if you have the email alerts module enabled (and you'll have to speak with your REDCap administrators about that) you can configure it to automatically email someone with information contained in the record, and to set the logic by which the email is sent.

This solution and the one you were recommended are the same with respect to form design, but they differ in the way the results are shared with the requestor. This solution does not require the user to have an account to access the results. I personally think the other solution (with user roles and DAGs) is the better solution.